# How to dynamially write a csv in duckdb?

Tags: duckdb

I am running the same analysis across multiple directories with the same file structure. I just change the `file_search_path` to the right directory and it works great. The issue I'm havin is how to dynamically save my csv files with different titles.

First, I change this config option *... and in reality, not using my Downloads folder for analysis!*

```sql
set file_search_path to '~/Downloads/some-folder/build-data/n-2000';

-- and I want to write to                       /output/result-n-2000.csv
```

Hardcoding is fine:

```sql
copy information_schema.tables to '~/Downloads/some-folder/output/result-n-2000.csv' ( header, delimiter ',')
```

But something like this does not work:

```sql
copy information_schema.tables to (
    select 
        value || '/../../output/result-n-' || regexp_extract(value, '\d+$') ||'.csv' as x
        -- ~/Downloads/some-folder/build-data/n-2000/../../output/result-n-2000.csv
    from duckdb_settings() 
    where name = 'file_search_path' 
) (header, delimiter ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

DuckDB expects a filename in the [`COPY TO` statement](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/copy.html#copy-to).

A possible workaround is to produce the string in the host language. E.g. if you run DuckDB from Python, you can run

```
duckdb.sql(f"""
    copy information_schema.tables to
        "{ duckdb.sql("select value || '/../../output/result-n-' || regexp_extract(value, '\d+$') ||'.csv' as x").fetchone()[0] }"
    from duckdb_settings() 
    where name = 'file_search_path' 
) (header, delimiter ',')
""")
```